# how to filter data based on date

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to display emails from json file. I want to display in this format:
Today
  Message: messagename  7:24AM
  from:janan,walker
  Message:messageName   4:20AM
  from:texas,Vanessa
Yesterday
  Message:messageName yesterday 4:55PM
  from: Hopkins,Alison
how to display in this format. here is my code:

```
<div >
     <div ng-repeat="email in inboxEmailList()">  
     <div id="emailDay">{{email.Date}}</div>
     <div id="emailRowContent">
            <div id="emailType">{{email.type}}: {{email.subject}}</div>
            <div id="emailTime">{{email.Time}}</div>
            <div id="emailFrom">{{email.from}}</div>
     </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the "shortTime" filter is what you are looking for:

```
<div id="emailDay">{{email.Date | date:'shortTime'}}</div>
```

And [here is a list](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) of all the built in date formatters in angular